# How i can create ajax success if else condition without json?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback

I created a form. I added many validations as requirement like required all fields. Check duplicate fields. Now I want if form submitted successfully without error reset my form if it has any error like duplicate email then show error Duplicate data found and don't reset form. I completed my code but tucked in a place I m returning false then it's not showing an error which I mentioned din called PHP file. So, how can I do it without using JSON?

```
$("#create_stock_out").click(function(){

    var form= new FormData();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var slip_no = $("#slip_no").val();
    var warehouse = $("#warehouse").val();
    var vendor = $("#vendor").val();
    var issued_by = $("#issued_by").val();
    var received_by = $("#received_by").val();
    var project = $("#project").val();

    form.append('subject',subject);
    form.append('slip_no',slip_no);
    form.append('warehouse',warehouse);
    form.append('vendor',vendor);
    form.append('issued_by',issued_by);
    form.append('received_by',received_by);
    form.append('project', project);
    form.append('method', "stock_out");



    $.ajax({
        url: 'Function/Function.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: form,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){

            //alert(data);
            $('#stock_out_result').html(""+data+"");
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }, 5000);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show us the code that you are working with ?

Comment: without seeing your existing code it's hard to suggest a specific solution. Please edit your question to include relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "without JSON"?

Comment: As I called here function.php. So i added there my code validations now I want if my PHP script now show any error empty this form after submission but if there is any error don't reset form only show error and I don't want to use JSON here.